# How to count sum of elements located in the upper left quarter of matrix

Tags: c++, xcode, function, matrix, sum

```
double CountSum(double **mat, int R, int C)
{
   double sum = 0.0;
   for(int i = 0; i < R / 2; i++)
   { 
     for(int j = 0; j < C / 2; j++)
     { 

         sum += mat[i][j];
     }
   }
   return sum;
}
```

Am I correct do this, or where I have mistakes? Or if you have some piece of advice on how to pass parameters to function, please tell me about that

Comment: what is `R` and `C` ? To see if it is correct you should write a test. For reviews of working code there is https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What's the point of passing `i` and `j` to that function? Shouldn't the parameters be R and C?

Comment: It is recommended that you paste whole code, so we have full picture what you have and what is wrong. Currently you are beginner so you do not know yet what is necessary to provide when asking programing question, so it is better to provide to much then to little.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `R` and `C` are number of rows and number of columns respectively, this code won't work.

If `R = 2` then `(R - 1) / 2 = 0` so the outer loop won't be executed, because `i < 0` is always false.

Don't subtract one, `R / 2` would be enough. There are corner cases though, when `R` and `C` aren't even.

About parameters: you can add `R` and `C` to parameter list instead of `i` and `j`. `(double **mat,  int R, int C)` and pass them respectively. From this current code, it looks like they are just global variables. `i` and `j` can be declared inside the function.

Code:

```
double CountSum(double **mat, int R, int C)
{
   double sum = 0.0;
   for(int i = 0; i < R / 2; i++)
   { 
     for(int j = 0; j < C / 2; j++)
     { 

         sum += mat[i][j];
     }
   }
   return sum;
}
```

This is the working code, I hope you understand how to use it - pass it an appropriate arguments. `R` and `C` being height and width of the matrix or dimensions can be called as well. Note that if `R` or `C` or both are odd, then you only get the sum of the smaller part always, if you want the bigger part, you should ceil it, thus use `(R + 1) / 2` instead of `R / 2` and similar for `C`.